# Time length of mp3 files for mp4chaps

Tags: bash, shell, sh, mp3

I have been struggling with a bit of bash code to generate an mp4chaps.chapters.txt file based on the time length of mp3 files so that when I have converted it to an audiobook (m4b) I can add the chapter information again.

I think I have solved it but I am curious if this can be done more elegantly?

My poc code (assumes that there are mp3 files in the folder you run this script in):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "00:00:00.000 Chapter 1" 
i=2
total_seconds=0
total_millis=0
for mp3 in *.mp3; do
  duration=$(ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format "${mp3}" | jq ".format.duration"|sed 's/"//g')
  millisecs="$(echo $duration | awk -F'.' '{print $2}')"
  millisecs="${millisecs#"${millisecs%%[!0]*}"}"
  total_millis=$((total_millis + millisecs))
  secs=$((total_millis / 1000000))
  total_millis=$((total_millis - (secs * 1000000)))
  total_seconds=$((total_seconds + $(echo $duration | awk -F'.' '{print $1}') + secs))
  hour=$((total_seconds / (60 * 60)))
  minutes=$(((total_seconds - (hour * 60 * 60)) / 60))
  seconds=$((total_seconds - (hour * 60 * 60) - (minutes * 60)))
  hour=$(printf "%02d" $hour)
  minutes=$(printf "%02d" $minutes)
  seconds=$(printf "%02d" $seconds)
  echo "$hour:$minutes:$seconds.${millisecs:0:3} Chapter $i"
  i=$((i + 1))
done
```

The format of an mp4chapts.chapters.txt file is like this:

```
00:00:00.000 Chapter 1
00:11:46.612 Chapter 2
00:22:55.525 Chapter 3
00:41:22.670 Chapter 4
01:09:17.337 Chapter 5
```

The ffprobe json format is:

```
{
    "format": {
        "filename": "Book with chapter 01.mp3",
        "nb_streams": 1,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "mp3",
        "format_long_name": "MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3)",
        "start_time": "0.025057",
        "duration": "706.612245",
        "size": "5657329",
        "bit_rate": "64050",
        "probe_score": 51,
        "tags": {
            "title": "a good book 01",
            "artist": "The Author",
            "album": "fantastic album information",
            "track": "01",
            "publisher": "Good Media, Inc",
            "genre": "Fiction",
            "comment": "Read by ...",
            "copyright": "2019",
            "date": "2021"
        }
    }
}
```

I use the duration from this json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
echo "00:00:00.000 Chapter 1"
i=2
total_millis=0
for mp3 in *.mp3; do
  duration=$(ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries format=duration "${mp3}" | sed -n 's/duration=//p')
  millisecs=$((${duration%.*} * 1000 + 10#${duration#*.} / 1000))
  ((total_millis += millisecs))
  hour=$((total_millis / 3600 / 1000))
  mins=$(((total_millis - hour*3600*1000) / 60 / 1000))
  secs=$(((total_millis - hour*3600*1000 - mins*60*1000) / 1000))
  millis=$((total_millis - hour*3600*1000 - mins*60*1000 - secs*1000))
  printf "%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d Chapter %d\n" "$hour" "$mins" "$secs" "$millis" "$i"
  ((i++))
done
```

I'm afraid it may still not be so elegant enough. I've unified the variable to accumulate
the amount time into `total_millis` which makes codes shorter
than the original. BTW your value of `millisecs` in the `echo`
line might be incorrect. It is directly calculated from the current chapter
without reflecting the value of `total_millis`.

**[Alternative]**

If your `date` command supports `-d` option, here is a cheat way:

```
echo "00:00:00.000 Chapter 1"
i=2
total_secs=0
for mp3 in *.mp3; do
  duration=$(ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries format=duration "${mp3}" | sed -n 's/duration=//p')
  total_secs=$(echo "$total_secs + $duration" | bc)
  day=$(date -d "@$total_secs" -u +%d)
  hour=$(( 10#$(date -d "@$total_secs" -u +%H) + (10#$day - 1) * 24 ))
  printf "%02d:%s Chapter %d\n" "$hour" "$(date -d "@$total_secs" -u +%M:%S.%3N)" "$((i++))"
done
```

The behavior of `date` command heavily depends on the platform and the solution above will not be portable.

Comment: WOW thanks! on linux they both seem to work fine! on MacOS I have to tweak it a bit. it seems that the -d option on date does not work on the second option and on the first alternative it does not handle a leading 0 well in the millisecs. Both are are a fine improvement though! I hope to see more alternatives otherwise I will √ you :-)

Comment: Oops after some more testing I have found another tricky bug in the alternative "date" version. It will not go past 23 hours. it will turn around to 0 and that is not wanted :-)
Sorry have to revert to my own version...

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. In the 1st code, I have forgot to handle the leading zeros such as: `081` or `009`, which is fixed now. Sorry for bothering you. As for the 2nd code, I did not imagine the total duration exceeds 24 hours...

Comment: I have also updated the `date` version. Now it works with the hours
exceeding 24. It is just a workaround accounting the `day`.